# open a Fragment by clicking on a recyclerview item and move to this fragment

Tags: android

i'm trying to open a Fragment by clicking on a recyclerview item, what i'm getting after clicking on item is both fragment toghter, i see the image from the fragment that i want to go to after the clicking on my recyclerview..Does anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager manger;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
        chatList.add(new Chat("send post card", " ", R.drawable.sentpostcard));
        chatList.add(new Chat("send greeting card", "happy holiday", R.drawable.greetingcard));
        chatList.add(new Chat("special designs", "choose a card", R.drawable.special));


        ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(chatList);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    // 1
    public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ChatViewHolder>{

        // 7
        private ArrayList<Chat> chats;

        // 8
        public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<Chat> chats) {
            this.chats = chats;
        }

        // 10
        @Override
        public ChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_item, parent, false); // false == do not attach to root
            return new ChatViewHolder(v);
        }

        // 11
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ChatViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind( chats.get(position) );
        }

        // 9
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return chats.size();
        }

        // 2
        public class ChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            //4
            private TextView textName, textChat;
            private ImageView imageChat;

            //we need to remember a chat for each view holder and we bind the chat object using the bind function
            //this will be useful later in the onClick Listener
            private Chat c;

            // view is the layout view ==> it contains all of the view in the layout file
            // 3
            public ChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                // 5
                textName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
                textChat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textChat);
                imageChat = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageChat);



                // 12
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            // 6
            public void bind(Chat chat){
                c = chat;
                textName.setText(chat.getName());
                textChat.setText(chat.getText());
                imageChat.setImageResource(chat.getImage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new FragA()).commit();


            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you write your activity_main layout ? If your fragment container is empty, it simply replace by your new FragA and keep the actual view active.

Comment: In the official page, there is a good example of Fragment Communication. They explain how to make a fragment change according to an item chosen in another fragment.(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). I think this can be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice to see you layout xml, but from what I can see:

Your recycler view is **not inside a fragment** - it is inside the **MainActivity**. You set it with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

When you do

`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new FragA()).commit();`

you **put your new fragment in the `fragment_container`** view group. But this **does not affect the activity** at all. So, you end up with **both views visible**.

There are two ways to fix this:

**The easy and hacky** one - set solid background (i.e `android:background="@android:color/black"`) to your fragment and add `android:clickable="true"` to it's root layout. Then you won't be able to see or interact with the activity that will be beneath your fragment.

**More proper way** - put your recycler view in a fragment, put that fragment in the `fragment_container` with `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, recyclerFragment).commit();`. Then it will be replaced with your new fragment on item click when you call `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new FragA()).commit();`

To be able to go back to the recycler view you will also need to call [addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) method